# Указать тип передаваемого обьекта

Tags: php

У меня есть в директории
models 3 файла. В первом файле написан интерфейс Model, в другом класс Cat, a в 3 класс Dog, которые этот интерфейс имплементируют. Потом я создал второю директорию где таким же способом создал интерфейс и классы имплементирующие его, но они называются DAO и CatDAO с DogDAO. В DAO интерфейсе я создал метод

```
public function writeNameOfObj(Model $obj);
```

А теперь мне надо имплементировать эти методы, но мне надо написать writeNameOfObj(Cat $obj) и writeNameOfObj(Dog $obj) соответственно. Вопрос в том как это сделать.

Comment: так и напишите, ругается что ли?

Comment: А вы используете пространства имён (namespace) ?

Comment: Что вы пытаетесь достичь этим?

Comment: Да, я использую неимспейсы. Daniel Protopopov,  я использую интерфейсы для обобщения нескольких классов, а потом эти интерфейсы использую для того чтоб указывать тип переменной передаваемой методу, который работает со всеми теми классами, что имплементируют тот интерфейс

Comment: Teran, у меня интерпретатор, к счастью, не ругается :), но мне надо сделать то, что я выше написал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Цитата из документации:

> Объявления методов в классе, реализующем интерфейс, должны точно совпадать с объявлениями, используемыми в интерфейсе, в противном случае будет вызвана фатальная ошибка.

Поэтому так, как Вы хотите, сделать нельзя